# get JSon.Stringify value in controller passed through Ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have javascript function as:

```
 function savePreObservationQuestionAnswers()
    {
    var lvPreObservationQuestionAnswers = $("#lvPreObservationQuestionAnswers").data("kendoListView");
            var data = lvPreObservationQuestionAnswers.dataSource.data();
var preObservationAnswers = new Array();
        var totalNumber = data.length;
       var ArtifactsModel = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < totalNumber; i++) {
                var currentDataItem = data[i];
                var myjson = [];
                var preObservationAnswers = {};
                preObservationAnswers["EH_PP_OBSRVNFRM_QSTN_ID"] = currentDataItem.EH_PP_OBSRVNFRM_QSTN_ID;
                preObservationAnswers["EH_PP_OBSRVNFRM_QSTN_ANSWR_TXT"] = currentDataItem.EH_PP_OBSRVNFRM_QSTN_ANSWR_TXT;

                myjson.push(preObservationAnswers);

                ArtifactsModel.push(myjson);

                //preObservationAnswers.push(currentDataItem.EH_PP_OBSRVNFRM_QSTN_ID, $('#txtanswer_' + currentDataItem.EH_PP_OBSRVNFRM_QSTN_ID).val());

                //lstArtifactsModel.push(ArtifactsModel);
            }
            alert(ArtifactsModel);
            $.ajax({

                type: "post",
                url: "/PP/savePreObservationAnswers",
                data: {
                    objAllData: JSON.stringify(ArtifactsModel)
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
    }
```

In controller I have code like:

```
public JsonResult savePreObservationAnswers(IEnumerable<ArtifactsModel> objAllData)
{
 return Json("");
}
```

But i am not getting values on objAllData in controller.

I am sure in javascript function i am getting proper values.

How can i do this?

**Edit:**

In ArtifactModel File i have properties like:

```
public int EH_PP_OBSRVNFRM_QSTN_ANSWR_ID { get; set; }
        public string EH_PP_OBSRVNFRM_QSTN_ANSWR_TXT { get; set; }
        public int EH_PP_ObservationID { get; set; }

        public int EH_PP_OBSRVFRM_QSTIN_SectionID { get; set; }

        public int EH_PP_OBSRVNFRM_QSTN_ID { get; set; }
        public string EH_PP_OBSRVFRM_QSTIN_SectionTitle { get; set; }
        public string EH_PP_OBSRVNFRM_QSTN_TXT { get; set; }

        public int EH_PP_OBSRVNFRM_QSTN_DSPSEQ { get; set; }
```

Comment: you don't have to Stringify your JSON object as your controller may allready espect JSON content. JSON.stringify is used to print JSON object in the javascript console. Just give a try without this function `$.ajax({..., data : ArtifactsModel, ...`

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the content type to JSON and stringify the whole object. For the moment you are using a "mixed mode" literal object/json which is not valid :

```
data: {objAllData: JSON.stringify(ArtifactsModel) }
```

should be :

```
data: JSON.stringify({ objAllData: ArtifactsModel })
```

Finally something like :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: "/PP/savePreObservationAnswers",
    data: JSON.stringify({ objAllData: ArtifactsModel }),
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```